OSC communication on local network between Android and OSX
I am trying to use OSC to communicate between a desktop computer (OSX) and an Android phone, which are both connected to the same wifi network. I'm working in Processing with the oscP5 library but I think eveything is fine in the code - this is, I think, an address issue or permissions Android side.
Here is my computer/desktop code:
import oscP5.*;
import netP5.*;

OscP5 oscP5;
NetAddress myRemoteLocation;
int colour = 255;

void setup()
{
  size(600, 600);

  /* start oscP5, listening for incoming messages at port 1200 */
  oscP5 = new OscP5(this,1200);
  println(this);
  
  /* the address of this device */
  myRemoteLocation = new NetAddress("127.0.0.1",1300);
}


void draw()
{
  background(0);
  
  fill(colour);
  circle(width/2, height/2, 200);
  
  int i = int(random(0, 200));
  if (i == 1) sendmessage();
}


void sendmessage()
{
  /* create the message */
  OscMessage myMessage = new OscMessage("/one");
  color c = color(random(0, 255), random(0, 255), random(0, 255));
  myMessage.add(c);
  
  /* send the message */
  println("Sending message: " + myMessage);
  oscP5.send(myMessage, myRemoteLocation); 
}


/* incoming osc message are forwarded to the oscEvent method */
void oscEvent(OscMessage theOscMessage)
{
  colour = theOscMessage.get(0).intValue();
}

This runs without issue and gives this in the console:
### [2024/11/7 17:12:20] PROCESS @ OscP5 stopped.
### [2024/11/7 17:12:20] PROCESS @ UdpClient.openSocket udp socket initialized.
### [2024/11/7 17:12:21] PROCESS @ UdpServer.start() new Unicast DatagramSocket created @ port 1200
### [2024/11/7 17:12:21] PROCESS @ UdpServer.run() UdpServer is running @ 1200
### [2024/11/7 17:12:21] INFO @ OscP5 is running. you (192.168.0.106) are listening @ port 1200

For some reason it does not state that the ip is 127.0.0.1 and gives 192.168.0.106 instead - this is the ip of the computer so both point to the same device but Android does this differently (see below).
Here is the code that runs on the Android phone:
import oscP5.*;
import netP5.*;

OscP5 oscP5;
NetAddress myRemoteLocation;
int colour = 255;


void setup()
{
  size(600, 600);

  /* start oscP5, listening for incoming messages at port 12000 */
  oscP5 = new OscP5(this,1300);
  println(this);
  
  /* the address of this device */
  myRemoteLocation = new NetAddress("127.0.0.1",1200);
}


void draw()
{
  background(0);
  
  fill(colour);
  circle(width/2, height/2, 200);
  
  int i = int(random(0, 200));
  if (i == 1) sendmessage();
}


void sendmessage()
{
  /* create the message */
  OscMessage myMessage = new OscMessage("/two");
  color c = color(random(0, 255), random(0, 255), random(0, 255));
  myMessage.add(c);

  /* send the message */
  println("Sending message: " + myMessage);
  oscP5.send(myMessage, myRemoteLocation); 
}


/* incoming osc message are forwarded to the oscEvent method */
void oscEvent(OscMessage theOscMessage)
{
  colour = theOscMessage.get(0).intValue();
}

and the manifest has internet and wifi permissions as follows
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="">
    <application android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="">
        <activity android:exported="true" android:name=".MainActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</manifest>

This also runs without issue and gives this in the console:
### [2024/11/7 17:29:23] PROCESS @ OscP5 stopped.
### [2024/11/7 17:29:23] PROCESS @ UdpClient.openSocket udp socket initialized.
### [2024/11/7 17:29:24] PROCESS @ UdpServer.start() new Unicast DatagramSocket created @ port 1300
### [2024/11/7 17:29:24] PROCESS @ UdpServer.run() UdpServer is running @ 1300
### [2024/11/7 17:29:24] INFO @ OscP5 is running. you (127.0.0.1) are listening @ port 1300

But, note the 127.0.0.1 ip address.
Both sketches run but don't communicate with each other. If I run the Android sketch on the desktop computer alongside the computer sketch they communicate without issue both ways. What am I missing/overlooking here?

I'm not following the question entirely, but why are you listening on 127.0.0.1?  That's the address for localhost and cannot be connected to from over the network.

because I'm not understanding the issue either - all I know is that it works on the same device on the same network but not on two separate devices on the same network.  I have also tried using the ips 192.168.0.106 and 192.168.0.108 (the ips of the computer and phone) and that also sdoes not work.

Try setting your listen addresses 0.0.0.0, and the connect addresses to the other machine.  Also, I don't know what OS X has for default firewalls but definitely check into that as well to make sure it isn't blocking you.

The oscP5 command for setting up listening doesn't take an ip as an argument new OscP5(this, 12000); - there was but it's depreciated. I tried it anyway but no change. There are also properties for oscP5 that can be set but no option to set the ip. I think you are right about a firewall. My router had its firewall activated and I turned it off but I'm still checking if there is something either OSX or Android side that is adding an additional layer of security.

My OSX computer does not have its firewall activated. Can't think of what to test now.

Don't use the localhost address 127.0.0.1 on both sides.  Instead use the other side's IP address in 'myRemoteLocation'.  I found the Android device's IP address under the WI-FI settings on my old Samsung tablet.  The computer's IP address should be shown in the console log when you run oscP5.  To confirm that messages are being sent both ways add appropriate println statements to the oscEvent() function.  eg, println("Message from Android") on the computer side and println("Message from Processing") on the Android side.  Color dots should be present on both sides.  Make certain to change the IP addresses below for your systems and add INTERNET to the Android permissions.
Desktop Processing code:
import oscP5.*;
import netP5.*;

OscP5 oscP5;
NetAddress myRemoteLocation;
int colour = 255;

void setup() {
  size(600, 600);
  /* start oscP5, listening for incoming messages at port 1200 */
  oscP5 = new OscP5(this, 1200);
  /* **IP address of Android device** */
  myRemoteLocation = new NetAddress("10.0.0.xx", 1200);
}


void draw() {
  background(0);

  fill(colour);
  circle(width/2, height/2, 200);

  int i = int(random(0, 200));
  if (i == 1) sendmessage();
}

void sendmessage() {
  /* create the message */
  OscMessage myMessage = new OscMessage("/one");
  color c = color(random(0, 255), random(0, 255), random(0, 255));
  myMessage.add(c);
  /* send the message */
  println("Sending message: " + myMessage);
  oscP5.send(myMessage, myRemoteLocation);
}

// incoming osc message are forwarded to the oscEvent method.
void oscEvent(OscMessage theOscMessage) {
  /* check if theOscMessage has the address pattern we are looking for. */
  if (theOscMessage.checkAddrPattern("/two") == true) {
    colour = theOscMessage.get(0).intValue();
    println("Received message from Android.");
  }
}


Android Device Processing code:
import oscP5.*;
import netP5.*;

OscP5 oscP5;
NetAddress myRemoteLocation;
int colour = 255;

void setup() {
  size(600, 600);
  /* start oscP5, listening for incoming messages at port 12000 */
    oscP5 = new OscP5(this,1200);  
  /* **IP address of computer** */
  myRemoteLocation = new NetAddress("10.0.0.xxx",1200);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  
  fill(colour);
  circle(width/2, height/2, 200);
  
  int i = int(random(0, 200));
  if (i == 1) sendmessage();
}

void sendmessage() {
  /* create the message */
  OscMessage myMessage = new OscMessage("/two");
  color c = color(random(0, 255), random(0, 255), random(0, 255));
  myMessage.add(c);

  /* send the message */
  println("Sending message: " + myMessage);
  oscP5.send(myMessage, myRemoteLocation); 
}

// incoming osc message are forwarded to the oscEvent method.
void oscEvent(OscMessage theOscMessage){
   /* check if theOscMessage has the address pattern we are looking for. */  
  if (theOscMessage.checkAddrPattern("/one") == true) {
    colour = theOscMessage.get(0).intValue();
    println("Received message from Processing.");
  }
}


In addition INTERNET permission must be added to Android app Manifest:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>


Are you sure that you are not causing a loop back in the sketches as they are using the same ip and port? One way to test is to add an if to the oscEvent if (theOscMessage.checkAddrPattern("/two") == true) to only check for the pattern from the other sketch. If you are testing both sketches on the same computer then they will work - my sketches did as well. As soon as I move them to two separate devices they fail to work.

If you change 'myRemoteLocation' on the Android side to your desktop address (192.x.x.x) then the Processing app should start working again.  The problem is that messages won't go the other way to the Android device.  I like your code addition to oscEvent() and think it is helpful.  The device firewall is a key suspect in my opinion.  The Android device is connected to your desktop so they are both using the same computer.  Bluetooth might be better.

Bingo.  If you use the ip address of your Android device as 'myRemoteLocation' on the Processing side then the whole thing works as expected.  To see that it is working add println messages to each oscEvent():  On the Processing side println("message from Android") and on the Android side println("message from Processing").  The key is to not use localhost, but use each others ip addresses.

"If you change 'myRemoteLocation' on the Android side to your desktop address (192.x.x.x) then the Processing app should start working again." - That's it! Yes receiving now on the desktop - many thanks. I don't get why they should be the same ip address - is this because the phone is tethered to the computer? They both have different ips according to the router. So if the router and mac don't have firewalls now and Android is still not getting messages that now suggests there is something Android side blocking messages. Is there something extra that needs to be turned on in developer options?

wahoo! yep that works. The naming in the oscP5 examples could be a little clearer - I understood these address as the addresses of the device the sketch is running on. Many thanks. I've upvoted your comments. If you want to add an answer I'll mark it as the correct one. Thanks again!
